# Set Hive variable with the output of a UDF

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, udf

I'm trying to set a Hive variable with the output of a UDF function, so I can use that value in a `INSERT INTO myTable` later in my .hql script.

This is the DDL of `myTable`:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(
CreationTimestamp TIMESTAMP,
Tablename CHAR(50),
LastExtractedTimestamp TIMESTAMP,
OozieJobID CHAR(40) 
);
```

The following is not working:

```
set hiveconf:ct=select current_timestamp;   
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('${hiveconf:ct}','test','2015-12-11 11:25:03.341','testID');
```

and also this one is not working (without quotes):

```
set hiveconf:ct=select current_timestamp;   
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (${hiveconf:ct}, 'test','2015-12-11 11:25:03.341','testID');
```

The result is that I get inserted a row in my table with a null value in place of my variable's value:

> null  test    2015-12-11 11:25:03.341     testID

So right now I'm using the following workaround:

```
INSERT INTO myTable select * from (select current_timestamp, 'test','2015-12-11 11:25:03.341','testID') as dummy;
```

Do you have any suggestion or better way to achieve this?

Thanks ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can use a UDF outside of a Hive query. Maybe you can, but I've never come across it. Given you're running a `.hql` script, why not execute a shell command and execute that instead? `! <command>` does it - see https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/how-to-run-unix-command-from-hive-shell for a basic example.

Comment: Thanks Bent, I'll probably keep the workaround for now, but I'll try the shell option and see how long it takes to execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible. Why ? Hive variables are inserted in the query when you submit the query and the query it is parsed, so *before* the UDF has even a chance to run at all.
Consider using something like oozie so you can actually build a modular workflow.